Allow only certain fields of Pydantic model to be passed to FastAPI endpoint
Let's say I have a Pydantic model with validation:
Name = Annotated[str, AfterValidator(validate_name)]

class Foo(BaseModel):
    id: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4)
    name: Name

And a FastAPI endpoint:
@app.post('/foos')
def create_foo(foo: Foo) -> Foo:
    save_to_database(foo)
    return foo

I only want the caller to be able to pass a value for name, but not for id. Is there any way to do something like this?
def create_foo(foo: Annotated[Foo, Body(include=['id'])]) -> Foo:

I know I can do:
@app.post('/foos')
def create_foo(name: Annotated[str, Body(embed=True)]) -> Foo:
    foo = Foo(name=name)
    save_to_database(foo)
    return foo

But then the implicit validation error handling doesn't work anymore, and I need to add more code to do that.
Any elegant way of handling that?

I think the general way it is done is to have a BaseFooModel that only has name, and then inherit it to create a model that has id. some related examples https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-template/blob/master/backend/app/models.py

Yes, a separate request model is also possible, but has other drawbacks. So I wanted to inquire whether I'm just overlooking something, or there really isn't anything built in for that.

As said above, I recommend using three models: ItemBase, ItemCreate (the data the EP receives, i.e. without the id attribute) and Item (the model with the full set of attributes, e.g. with the id). ItemCreate and Item both inherit from ItemBase. So your create_foo would accept ItemCreate in input and return Item as output

Option 1
You could hide/exclude a field on object instantiation/creation, by using Private model attributes. Pydantic will exclude model attributes that have a leading underscore. As described in the linked documentation:

Attributes whose name has a leading underscore are not treated as
fields by Pydantic, and are not included in the model schema. Instead,
these are converted into a "private attribute" which is not validated
or even set during calls to __init__, model_validate, etc.

Note, though, that:

As of Pydantic v2.1.0, you will receive a NameError if trying to use
the Field function with a private attribute. Because private
attributes are not treated as fields (as mentioned earlier), the Field() function cannot be applied.

Thus, in Pydantic V2, you could use the PrivateAttr instead of Field function, along with the default_factory parameter, in order to define a callable that will be called to generate a dynamic default value (i.e., different for each model instance)—in this case, a UUID.
Woriking Example
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, PrivateAttr
from uuid import UUID, uuid4


class Foo(BaseModel):
    _id: UUID = PrivateAttr(default_factory=uuid4)
    name: str


app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/foo")
def create_foo(foo: Foo):
    print(foo._id)
    return foo

Option 2
Simply a variation of the above (see the documentation for more details), without using the PrivateAttr and default_factory. Instead, the __init__ method is directly used to automatically generate a new UUID.
Woriking Example
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from uuid import UUID, uuid4


class Foo(BaseModel):
    _id: UUID
    name: str
    
    def __init__(self, **data):
        super().__init__(**data)
        self._id = uuid4()


app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/foo")
def create_foo(foo: Foo):
    print(foo._id)
    return foo

Option 3
Another way would be to use two different Pydantic models, one meant to be used by the user, while the second one, which should inherit from the first (base) one, by the backend. Similar examples are given in FastAPI's Extra Models documentation, as well as in Full Stack FastAPI Template.
Woriking Example
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from uuid import UUID, uuid4


class BaseFoo(BaseModel):
    name: str


class Foo(BaseFoo):
    id: UUID = Field(default_factory=uuid4)
    

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/foo")
def create_foo(base: BaseFoo):
    foo = Foo(**base.model_dump())  # Foo(name=base.name) should work as well
    print(foo.id)
    return base

Option 4
This is a variation of Options 1 and 2, modified in a way that would allow one to define their private attribute without using an underscore (if that's a requirement in your project), but still get the same result as if any of the previous options were used.
In this case, the Field function is used. Since the attribute is meant to be hidden from the client, you should need to set the exclude attribute to True, so that if you return the Pydantic model instance back to the client, that attribute won't be included. Also, in Pydantic V2, you could use the SkipJsonSchema annotation, in order to skip that field from the generated JSON schema, as in Swagger UI autodocs, for instance (for Pydantic V1 solutions, please have a look at this github post and its related discussion).
Now, there is nothing from stopping the client to pass the hidden attribute in their JSON request body, regardless of hiding it from the schema and defining it as optional/non-required (i.e., Field(default=None)). Since this solution uses a regular Field and not PrivateAttr, using the default_factory attribute, as in Option 1 and as shown below:
class Foo(BaseModel):
    id: SkipJsonSchema[UUID] = Field(default_factory=uuid4, exclude=True)
    name: str

would not be the most suitalbe approach, as if the client passed a value for id, that value would be assigned to that field.
However, using a similar approach to Option 2, i.e., replacing default_factory with __init__ (which is used to generate the UUID for id field), even if the client passed a value for id, it would be "ignored", and the one generated by the model would be assigned to the field.
Woriking Example
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from uuid import UUID, uuid4
from pydantic.json_schema import SkipJsonSchema


class Foo(BaseModel):
    id: SkipJsonSchema[UUID] = Field(default=None, exclude=True)
    name: str
    
    def __init__(self, **data):
        super().__init__(**data)
        self.id = uuid4()
    

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/foo")
def create_foo(foo: Foo):
    print(foo.id)
    return foo


This answer and this answer might also prove helpful to future readers.
How to populate a Pydantic model without default_factory or __init__ overwriting the provided field value
While this is not an issue when using Option 3 provided above (and one could opt going for that option, if they wish), it might be when using one of the remaining options, depending on the method used to populate the model.
For instance, if you populate the model using Foo(**data), where data is an already existing model instance from your database, using one of the options described earlier (besides Option 3 that does not suffer from this issue), the _id or id value (included in the data dictionary) that is passed to the model would be replaced/overwritten by a newly generated one.
To overcome this issue, the following solutions are suggested.
Solution 1
After calling Foo(**data), you could simply replace the newly generated id with the existing one, by setting the value for that specific field to data["_id"] or data["id"] (depending on the Option used).
Example:
data = {"name": "foo", "_id": "7c4308a2-0f32-1243-b2ad-bf214a24a5aa"}
f = Foo(**data)
f._id = data["_id"]

Solution 2
Instead of using Foo(**data), which uses the model's __init__ method, and hence, a new id value is generated when called—for the sake of completeness, it should also be noted that there is an additional method, i.e., model_validate(), which is very similar to the __init__ method of the model, except it takes a dict or an object rather than keyword arguments—one could use the model_construct() method (in Pydantic V1, this used to be construct()).
As per the documentation:

Creating models without validation
Pydantic also provides the model_construct() method, which
allows models to be created without validation. This can be useful
in at least a few cases:

when working with complex data that is already known to be valid (for    performance reasons)
when one or more of the validator functions are non-idempotent, or
when one or more of the validator functions have side effects that    you don't want to be triggered.

Warning
model_construct() does not do any validation, meaning it can create models which are invalid. You should only ever use the
model_construct() method with data which has already been validated,
or that you definitely trust.
[...]
When constructing an instance using model_construct(), no
__init__ method from the model or any of its parent classes will be
called, even when a custom __init__ method is defined.

Example:
data = {"name": "foo", "_id": "7c4308a2-0f32-1243-b2ad-bf214a24a5aa"}
f = Foo.model_construct(**data)


Not the kind of solutions I hoped for, but I'll accept that there's no better way. Thank you!

You are welcome. May I please ask what's the issue with Option 1 or 2, for instance? Is it that you can't have the private attribute, i.e., _id, printed/passed to db when using the foo obejct and needs to be called individually, e.g., foo._id?

It just seems like something that has an unnecessary impact on the rest of the code, to always have to use _id instead of a plain id. In my case I'm also serialising this into a simple NoSQL store, where the _ would seem odd, so I'd have to do some additional mapping there.

I have just added a 4th option that might meet your requirements (however, I would still probably go for one of the previous options).

Mmm, that’s kind of doing the opposite of what’s desired. The id should be included in the JSON response, and should not generate from scratch every time the model is used. I just don’t want the client to be able to POST or PUT the id themselves. I’d imaging that to be a fairly common use case actually‽

"The id should be included in the JSON response..." - In that case, you could simply remove exclude=True. "...should not generate from scratch every time the model is used. " - The whole purpose of default_factory (or the alternatvie way mentioned in the docs and demonstrated in Options 2 & 4) is when you want the value of a field "to be dynamic (i.e. different for each model)", as in the case of a UUID.

Yes, I want it to be different for each new instance. I don't want the id to be overwritten by a newly generated id every time I revive an already existing instance from my database with Foo(**data).

The answer above has been updated with relevant solutions. Hope this works for you.

That's an option I suppose, thanks. For the time being I went with my last sample I showed in my question + a try..except to handle validation errors; but for more complex cases with more parameters I'll consider one of your suggestions.
